# How can I substitute our site name in the place that the URL usually appears in the Google search results?

Tags: seo, google, url, search-results

Below is a screen shot of a query on Google. The URL usually appears where the green text is. How do you control what that says?

For my specific site it displays the URL. I want to put my business name there.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot looks like you are searching on a mobile device? What platform specifically? Does the search phrase affect the results? I've tried duplicating the results you are seeing (Safari on iPad), but I only see the green URL for those same two results - not the "site name" that you appear to be seeing?

Answer (score 4):

For internal sections of the site, a navigation chain can be displayed in the snippet (with green color), revealing more information about the structure of the web resource and the position of the page in this structure.

To be displayed in the snippet:

- it's desirable to set up breadcrumbs and do it correctly (with meta
  tags, for example [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) );
- the tree of sections of the site should correspond to the URL, that
  is, if the product belongs to the category of "some new posts", then
  in the URL it should have an intermediate page `/some-new-posts/` and
  URL should look something like this:

  ```
  https://example.com/some-new-posts/new-post-{name}
  ```
- it's desirable that a title and a text of the link (any) were similar.

Comment: I have og meta data within my files. However, my company name is not displaying like the example illustration above.